# Cannot find package when running golang test

Tags: go, testing, import, go-modules, testify

When I run go tests I get the error:

```
cannot find package "github.com/stretchr/testify/assert" in any of:
    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.17.6/libexec/src/github.com/stretchr/testify/assert (from $GOROOT)
    /Users/MyName/go/src/github.com/stretchr/testify/assert (from $GOPATH)
```

I do however see that my local installation of stretchr and other tools ARE in `/Users/MyName/golang/pkg/mod/github.com`

How do I get golang to look in the right place for these installations? I thought it would be grabbing the resource from github if the import is pointing to the repo.

Are my installations in the "wrong" spot, and should I move them to where golang would look for them by default?

I have been able to test using stretchr before, but upgrading the package didn't change anything.

Running `go get github.com/stretchr/testify` and `go mod tidy` also didn't seem to change the behavior.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: The error makes it look like you are not using modules. Are you running the test from within the module?

Comment: Yes I am using modules and am running the test from within the module.

Answer (score -1):

Run "go mod init" whilst in your folder with your code, then go mod tidy.
It should work, if not, try go get ... then try this again.
Some IDE's such as VSCode delete imports when saving if they're unrecognised, or not used, so make sure when you run go mod init, and tidy, that the import is actually in the file

Comment: I tried this and am getting the same error.

Answer (score -1):

I closed VS Code and re-opened, and it's working now...